# Awk print exact fields when finding an exact match

Tags: bash, awk

I have a persons.dat file containing information.

Here's an example line.

> ```
> 1129|Lepland|Carmen|female|1984-02-18|228T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
> ```

1129 is the ID.

I am asked to display the information of anyone based on their ID,in particular their firstname (Carmen), (Lastname = Lepland) and date of Birth (1984-02-18) separated by a space.

I have stored the id in a shell variable IDNumber as shown below:

```
for arg1 in $@;do # Retrieve ID Number
if  [ $1 = "-id" ];then
        IDNumber="$2"
fi
shift
done
```

How can I use awk to display the exact fields of one ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line argument parsing of the shell script is a bit confusing like that, since `arg1` is not used.
And even after it finds `-id` and assigns `$2` to `IDNumber`,
the iteration continues.
For example when the arguments are `-id 3`,
after `IDNumber=3`,
the iteration continues, checking `if [ 3 = "-id" ]`.
Also, the `"$1"` in `if [ $1 = ... ]` should be double-quoted,
otherwise the script will crash if there is an empty argument.

Here's one way to fix these issues:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    if [ "$1" = -id ]; then
        id=$2
    fi
    shift
done
```

Then you can use `id` with Awk like this:

```
awk -F'|' -v id="$id" '$1 == id {print $3, $2, $5}' persons.dat
```

That is:

- Set `|` as the field separator
- Set `id` variable in Awk to the value of `$id` in the shell
- Find the record in the input where the first field (`$1`) is equal to `id`
- Print the columns you need

Comment: Change the order to $3,$2,$5 and you’re answering OP exactly.

Comment: You are the best. It took me 4 hours to find this.Can you explain why my argument parsing with for is incorrect. Isn't it the same as your while ?

Comment: Thanks @MarcLambrichs, well spotted!

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΓαλάνης I added more explanation about that